# Insert jpg into html R markdown by values in dataframe

Tags: html, r-markdown, knitr, jpeg

I have the following problem:

I want to create a html R markdown report which will print a table of this form.

```
df <- data.frame(c("Apple", "Tomato", "Banana"),
                 c("symbol 01", "symbol 02", NA),
                 c(NA, "symbol 03", "symbol 04"))
colnames(df) = c("Name", "col1", "col2")
```

I have a folder which contains images/symbols named like the values in the columns 2 and 3, i.e."symbol01.jpg". When I knit my markdown report of my dataframe, I want to display/insert those images instead of the values in the columns "col1" and "col2"

like i.e. Apple and right next to it symbol01.jpg

Can someone give me an idea how to do this?